# How to create a mock user by wrong password in the @WithMockUser way during the JUnit test?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, junit

In the `@WithMockUser` approach, the `createSecurityContext` method of `WithMockUserSecurityContextFactory` is used to create a security context with a mocked user. However, the authentication object is always created in an authenticated state. This means that if the authentication object is always authenticated, the password validation cannot be tested. As a result, testing for the wrong password case cannot be done.

[WithMockUserSecurityContextFactory#createSecurityContext(WithMockUser withUser)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Jji.png)

Here is the source:
SecurityConfiguration

```
@Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {

        String encPW = passwordEncoder.encode("123456");
        log.debug(encPW);
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password(encPW)
                //.password("123456")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("123456"))
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf((csrf)
                        -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/demo/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((ah)
                        -> ah
                        .requestMatchers("/demo/authenticate").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                ;
        return http.build();
    }
```

Test

```
//@WithMockUser(username = "no_exist_user", password = "123456777") //TEST NG
@Test
    void testHelloByWrongPw() throws Exception {

        mvc.perform(
                        post("/demo/authenticate")
                                .with(httpBasic("no_exist_user", "123456777"))
                                .content("{\"a1\":\"123\"}")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .queryParam("a1","123")
                )
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not works like what you expected .`@WithMockUser` is just intended to configure an user object with certain permissions for the current user who is successfully authenticated .It cannot simulate if an user fails to authenticate. Because if an user fails to authenticate , no user objects exist for him and hence nothing to configure.

So `@WithMockUser` is a tool more about for testing authorization but not authentication.

If you want to test an user sending a request with an incorrect password, just test it using the normal `@WebMvcTest` and use `MockMvc` to configure the HTTP request with an incorrect password like what you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.


If I use the MockHttpServletRequestBuilder#with(UserDetailsRequestPostProcessor) 
like following code, it is also fail to test. 
Is that the same reason?



`code`
        mvc.perform(
                        post("/demo/authenticate")                                .with(user(User.withUsername("no_exits_user").password("12345677").build()))
`code`

Comment: yes. you are right.